# Find the center of the square (?) with a closed form or a reasonable accuracy .

Tags: definite-integrals, coordinate-systems, gamma-function, symmetry

Well here is my problem :

Problem :

Define :

### $$f\left(x\right)=x^{(x!)^{(x)^{x!}}},f(1-x),g(x)=x,g(1-x)$$

These curves define a square (?) see the plot below :

[image: TheSquare]

I want to find the cartesian coordinate of the square's center .

As attempt and by symmetry I know it's something like $(0.5,y)$ . Unfortunetaly I cannot find the remainders .

If there is no closed form how to find it  with a reasonable accuracy ?

Additional question :

I have a doubt on the geometric form so : Is it a square ?

partial answer as remarks :

This definitively not a square at least in plotting it and due to the equation of $f(x)$ .

To find the center of the pseudo-square we can use derivative at :

$$f'(a)=1$$

And next we have an exact square . Remains to show the closed form mention in eyeballfrog comment .

Comment: Hallo
y=(0,5+f(0,5))/2=0.52
it is difficult to read you f(x), can you add some brackets?
you sketch looks like $f(x)=x^{x!}$

Comment: @Trula Hola is it cleaner for the eyes now ?

Comment: @Trula no this what I have tried for first time (your value of $y$) but it's not true (plot)

Comment: Can you give the Desmos link so we can interact with the graph?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Why? insert by yourself the different functions as kids play !^^

Comment: The closed form answer is $(1+2^{1-(\sqrt{\pi}/2)^{2^{-\sqrt{\pi}/2}}})/4$. Is that closed enough? If so I'll write up the derivation.

Comment: @eyeballfrog It seems very unexpected ...I would be very happy if you can show it .

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing is that we already know that the center of the square lies on $x = 1/2$. That means that the $y$ coordinate of the center of the square is halfway between $1/2$ and $f(1/2)$. Using $(1/2)! = \sqrt{\pi}/2$, we get
$$
f(1/2) = (1/2)^{(\sqrt{\pi}/2)^{(1/2)^{\sqrt{\pi}/2}}} = 2^{-(\sqrt{\pi}/2)^{2^{-\sqrt{\pi}/2}}}.
$$
Not the cleanest of expressions, but it works. We then use this to find $y$:
$$
y = \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{2} + f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right] = \frac{1}{4}\left[1 + 2^{1-(\sqrt{\pi}/2)^{2^{-\sqrt{\pi}/2}}}\right].
$$
If you wanted to approximate this value, note that $
\sqrt{\pi}/2 \approx 0.886$ is somewhat close to $1$, so you could write $\sqrt{\pi}/2 = 1 - \delta$ and then expand in power series in $\delta$. To first order you'd get $y \approx 1/2 + (\delta/8)\ln 2\approx 0.50986$, only 0.26% off the true value $0.51120$.